# Java: Adding default methods to Iterable/List/...?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm seriously considering to add default methods into Java 8 `Iterable/List/`etc. , instead of the current approach via `stream/static` methods, which has made my code rather long and difficult-to-read, especially for numerous small pieces of code where simple list filter/combine is required, such as:
`printLines(myList.filter(a -> a.alive).map(a -> a.name))`

I understand that would require all environments that compile and execute my code to have specific jars in `jre\lib\endorsed`, but it doesn't matter to our project since it will have to ship with embedded **JRE**. The binary compatibility is okay as described in Java 8 document. The endorsed method is also ignored in binary license (unlike -Xbootclasspath). What else should I consider? Have anyone or any project done that already?

Comment: That's quite an extreme solution. I hope you have the experience to back that choice up. Your example problem certainly wouldn't warrant something like this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but this sounds like one of the awfulest ideas ever.  I would not want to be part of a project where I basically couldn't trust the javadoc because someone has been mucking with the library.

Comment: Of course I have no prior experience of modifying JRE class library, nor would most people have... Those are interfaces and I'll only add new default methods which are not implemented anywhere, so the problem of compatibility seems minimum for now.

Comment: I meant experience in general. Posing a problem like "code is long and difficult to read, due to list filter/combines" and determining that the best way to solve it is to modify the JRE classes sounds a bit dubious. How does your code look like? What design patterns do you use?

Comment: What does this have to do with design patterns? I spent years coding on C# and not used to tolerating the lack of basic language features and poor API in general. If you don't have any technical objections, I'll just ignore your further comments.

Comment: @AqD This has everything to do with design patterns. Following proper design patterns should ideally result in short, readable code which would not warrant modifying JRE classes.

Comment: What design patterns would save me from something like printLines(IterablesHelper......(IterableHelper.map(IterableHelper.filter(myList, a -> a.alive), a -> a.name)...)? Do you even realize iterable functions are one of the most basic functions (like String functions) and they're practically used everywhere in high-level languages? If the String class is without String.length(), should I accept that too and change my 'pattern' of code?

Comment: Err, why do you use an IterableHelper class instead of using Java 8 streams? `printLines(list.stream().filter(a -> a.alive).map(a -> a.name).collect(toList())`. It seems like you simply didn't learn how to use streams.

Comment: Design patterns are nothing but widely accepted best practices.  Unless you have reasons to believe that either yourself or your circumstances are unique, it just plain common sense to learn how to things right and why so.

Comment: JB: because stream introduces too much code for Iterable. It's also incompatible with existing types, hence the need of extra stream() and toList() which is rather a waste. And due to lack of extension method in language level, I can do nothing to fix the situation. PM 77-1: It's quite common in functional languages and C# to do things like that.

Comment: It's also quite common for programmers to complain about features they like in one language that are missing in another.  But learning to tolerate that is part of being a professional.  Trying to modify the language yourself (and that's what modifying the runtime libraries would be, in effect) is, as Kayaman said, an extreme way to deal with this frustration.

Comment: You might be able to define your own class that implements `List`, defines a constructor that takes a reference to another `List`, implements the `List` methods by delegating them to the referenced list, and adds your new methods.  Then you could say `new EnhancedList(myList).filter(a->a.alive).map(a->a.name).`  You could add methods from `ArrayList` that would throw an exception if the base list isn't an `ArrayList`.  Maybe not an ideal solution, but orders of magnitude better than mucking with the libraries.

Comment: *stream introduces too much code for Iterable*: what does that mean? *It's also incompatible with existing types*: what does that mean? You can create a stream for any Iterable with `StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)`. How is that too much code? I find it strange that you complain about the extra stream() call needed, and replace it with your ugly IterableHelper. You could also use Guava's FluentIterable if you desire.

Comment: JB: None of them are ideal. guava lacks a few functions I need, and again because of the lack of extension method in Java I can't fix it, same problem with Stream, besides more code and unnecessary collecting to list. ajb: But I don't have to tolerate, since Java 8 has default methods now.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from making your printLines() method accept a Stream instead of a List. So no need to call collect(toList()). I think you'll never be happy until you use C# and abandon Java.

Comment: You see, the problem with Stream is that it's not directly compatible with existing APIs, which usually take Collection or Iterable. Anyway I made the conversion and now things look a lot better; apparently there are a lot more use of "endorsed" I could do in future.

Answer (score 0):

The jre\lib\endorsed works. Tested with running Eclipse/IntelliJ/NetBeans and LWJGL/JOGL demos without any problem.

I have to use source from OpenJDK to avoid license problems; New default methods are put in separated classes, such as this:

```java
public interface Iterable<T> extends IterableExt<T> {
    Iterator<T> iterator();
    ....
}
```

```java
public interface IterableExt<T> {
    default boolean all(Predicate<? super T> filter)
    {
        for (T item : (Iterable<T>) this)
        {
            if (!filter.test(item))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    default Iterable<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> filter)
    {
        Iterable<T> thiz = (Iterable<T>) this;
        return () -> new FilteredIterator<>(thiz.iterator(), filter);
    }
}
```

Deployment is simple enough: just wrap everything into jar and put into %JRE_HOME%\lib\endorsed. Since it's applied to entire system and locked on Windows, it'd be impossible to upgrade without stopping all Java programs.

Another problem is the classes compiled by Eclipse would not work when referenced by javac later (bad class file etc), but recompiling by javac works for both.

EDIT: I uploaded the source to https://github.com/AqD/JXTN (.axi project) under public domain.